# Web page that calculates results of four arithmetic operations for two numbers

Tags: javascript, beginner, calculator

This is the code that I have written for a simple mathematical application using javascript. In accordance with the task, I broke the program into functions that perform the computations.
But I guess my code looks very large:

```js
function addTwoN(a, b){
    return (a + b);
}
function subtractNumb(a,b){
    return (a - b);
}
function multiplNumb(a,b){
    return (a * b);
}
function divisNumb(a,b){
    return (a / b);
}
function myFunction(){
    const firstInput = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
    const secondInput = document.getElementById("second-number").value;
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    var firstNumb = Number(firstInput);
    var secondNumb = Number(secondInput);
    var sum = addTwoN(firstNumb, secondNumb);
    var sbtr = subtractNumb(firstNumb, secondNumb);
    var multi = multiplNumb(firstNumb, secondNumb);
    var divis = divisNumb(firstNumb, secondNumb); 
    var str = 
    firstNumb + " + " + secondNumb + " = " + sum + "<br>" +
    firstNumb + " - " + secondNumb + " = " + sbtr + "<br>" +
    firstNumb + " * " + secondNumb + " = " + multi + "<br>" +
    firstNumb + " / " + secondNumb + " = " + divis; 
    result.innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<form class="ml-5 mb-5 mt-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>What is the first number?</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="" id="first-number" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); myFunction()" min="0" style="width: 90px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>What is the second number?</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); myFunction()" id="second-number" min="0" style="width: 90px">
    </div>
</form>
<div class="ml-5" id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious simple change is to avoid making unnecessary variable assignments.  For example, just write

```
const a = Number(document.getElementById("first-number").value);
```

instead of

> ```
> const firstInput = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
> …
> var firstNumb = Number(firstInput);
> ```

You should also be more consistent with naming (e.g. `addTwoN` vs. `multiplNumb`).  `myFunction` needs a better name; I suggest `onInputUpdated`.

The code could be simplified by treating each of the four operations as data.  Then, you apply the same transformation on each element of the `operations` list.

```js
const operations = [
    {symbol: '+', callback: function(a, b) { return a + b }},
    {symbol: '-', callback: function(a, b) { return a - b }},
    {symbol: '*', callback: function(a, b) { return a * b }},
    {symbol: '/', callback: function(a, b) { return a / b }},
];

function onInputUpdated() {
    const a = Number(document.getElementById("first-number").value);
    const b = Number(document.getElementById("second-number").value);
    const result = operations.map(function(op) {
        return a + " " + op.symbol + " " + b + " = " + op.callback(a, b);
    }).join('<br>');
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<form class="ml-5 mb-5 mt-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>What is the first number?</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="" id="first-number" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); onInputUpdated()" min="0" style="width: 90px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>What is the second number?</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); onInputUpdated()" id="second-number" min="0" style="width: 90px">
    </div>
</form>
<div class="ml-5" id="result"></div>
</body>
```